# Autosort JTable after dataModelUpdate

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

Keep sorting after data model changes.

**Expected behaviour:**
I click one of the columnheaders to sort, and Its supposed to keep sorting that column as the dataModel changes. That is, once you choose a column to sort by, you shouldn't have to click on it manually after each update of the underlying data model to see it in that order.

**Current Behaviour:**
Seems to reset the sorting after data model changes. That is, as if I havent clicked any column. Update of data model makes it jumbled again.

**What I tryed:**
I wrote a small program that mimics the change of the underlying datamodel through a for loop, every 2000 milliseconds.
Since the original data changes so much from update to update, I chose to change the data with DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(), instead of row by row which seems bulky if lots of rows change.
I used what made sense to me, that is TableRowSorter.setSortsOnUpdates(), to well... sort after updates x).
I left commented out code to show that I tryed different approaches, some found here on stackexchange, but couldnt make it work anyway.
I tryed reading into the api and found this as a possible problemmaker:

> If the underlying model structure changes (the modelStructureChanged method is invoked) the following are reset to their default values: Comparators by column, current sort order, and whether each column is sortable. The default sort order is natural (the same as the model), and columns are sortable by default.

This was found in API documentation: [TableRowSorter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html)

I guess one might say I do *not* want it to reset to default sort order, but rather keep the last chosen one. Surely there must be a somewhat easy way to stop it from doing that?

Btw Im a noob, please keep that in mind when answering and I hope I made sense in trying to explain the expected behaviour.

**My code sofar:**

```
package TestTable;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import ui.Runner;

public class starter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        starter start = new starter();
        Vector<String> columNames = new Vector<>();
        columNames.add("index");
        columNames.add("years");
        columNames.add("weight");
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        Vector<Object> dataInData = new Vector<>();
        Random dice = new Random();

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columNames);
        //table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(table);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        //MyRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new MyRowSorter<>();
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        //DefaultRowSorter sorter = (DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter();
        //TableModelEvent ev = new TableModelEvent(model);
        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);//<---------------<<<<<

        data.add(new Vector<Object>());
        data.add(new Vector<Object>());
        data.add(new Vector<Object>());

        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            dataInData = data.get(x);
            for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
                dataInData.add(dice.nextInt(10));
            }
        }

        for(int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                dataInData = data.get(x);
                for(int y = 0; y < dataInData.size(); y++) {
                    dataInData.set(y, dice.nextInt(10));
                }
            }

            model.setDataVector(data, columNames);//<-------------------<<
            //model.fireTableDataChanged();
            //sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
            //sorter.rowsUpdated(0, data.size() -1);
            model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() -1 );
            //model.fireTableDataChanged();
            //model.fireTableChanged(ev);
            //model.fireTableStructureChanged();
            //sorter.rowsUpdated(0, data.size() );
            //sorter.sort();
        }
    }

    public static class MyFrame extends JFrame{
        JTable table;
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(300, 500);
        JScrollPane pane;
        Vector<String> columNames = new Vector<>();
        Vector<Vector<Object>> dataVector;
        Runner thread;
        int[] i = {0, 1, -1};

        public MyFrame(JTable table) {
            pane = new JScrollPane(table);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            setSize(300, 500);
            setPreferredSize(dim);
            setMinimumSize(dim);
            setTitle("Failing autoupdate of JTable");
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            add(pane);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `setDataVector` will trigger a `TableStructureChanged` event which, from memory, will reset the row sorter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just step past the thread violation issues for a second.

Calling `setDataVector` on the `DefaultTableModel` triggers a `TableStructureChanged`, which forces the `JTable` to, amongst other things, discard/reset the `rowSorter`, instead, simply update the values in model directly, for example

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < table.getColumnCount(); y++) {
        model.setValueAt(dice.nextInt(10), x, y);
    }
}
```

I tested this using a Swing `Timer` instead, to ensure that the updates were occurring the EDT properly

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() {
        Vector<String> columNames = new Vector<>();
        columNames.add("index");
        columNames.add("years");
        columNames.add("weight");
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        Random dice = new Random();

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columNames);
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(table);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
        sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);//<---------------<<<<<

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            model.addRow(new Vector());
            for (int y = 0; y < table.getColumnCount(); y++) {
                model.setValueAt(dice.nextInt(10), x, y);
            }
        }

        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < table.getColumnCount(); y++) {
                        model.setValueAt(dice.nextInt(10), x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        JTable table;
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(300, 500);
        JScrollPane pane;
        Vector<String> columNames = new Vector<>();
        Vector<Vector<Object>> dataVector;
        int[] i = {0, 1, -1};

        public MyFrame(JTable table) {
            pane = new JScrollPane(table);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            setSize(300, 500);
            setPreferredSize(dim);
            setMinimumSize(dim);
            setTitle("Failing autoupdate of JTable");
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            add(pane);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

> I chose to change the data with DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(), instead of row by row which seems bulky if lots of rows change

Okay, that seems reasonable.  The only solution I seem to be able to get to work for this is to replace the `RowSorter`, but use the `sortKeys` from the old `RowSorter`

Just using the same instance of `RowSorter` didn't work for me

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.RowSorter;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }

    Random dice = new Random();

    public Main() {
        Vector<String> columNames = new Vector<>();
        columNames.add("index");
        columNames.add("years");
        columNames.add("weight");
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

        JTable table = new JTable();
        makeModel(table, columNames);
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame(table);

        Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                makeModel(table, columNames);
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void makeModel(JTable table, Vector columnNames) {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            Vector row = new Vector();
            for (int y = 0; y < model.getColumnCount(); y++) {
                row.add(dice.nextInt(10));
            }
            model.addRow(row);
        }
        TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
        RowSorter<? extends TableModel> oldSorter = table.getRowSorter();
        if (oldSorter != null) {
            sorter.setSortKeys(oldSorter.getSortKeys());
        }

        table.setModel(model);
        table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }

    public static class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        JTable table;
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(300, 500);
        JScrollPane pane;
        Vector<String> columNames = new Vector<>();
        Vector<Vector<Object>> dataVector;
        int[] i = {0, 1, -1};

        public MyFrame(JTable table) {
            pane = new JScrollPane(table);
            table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            setSize(300, 500);
            setPreferredSize(dim);
            setMinimumSize(dim);
            setTitle("Failing autoupdate of JTable");
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            add(pane);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Just note, that this kind of update will also remove the column/row selection as well

> I chose to change the data with DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(), instead of row by row which seems bulky if lots of rows change

Another choice would be not to use a `DefaultTableModel`, but implement your own using `AbstractTableModel`, where you do a "batch" update to the underlying model data and then trigger a `tableDataChanged` event. You'd have to be careful to make sure you don't modify the data which might be requested by the `JTable` until you've completed the batch update

Comment: (1+) for recreating the RowSorter with the old SortKeys.

Comment: @camickr I think it's a little hacky, I think I prefer the concept of create a `TableModel` with a batch support - at least this won't clear the column/row selection but still uses only a single event

Comment: On second thought you are correct, the model should look after everything, The application should not have to play with the RowSorter just because the data changes.. I take back the 1+ for the suggestion to reuse the old sortKeys, but restore the 1+ for the suggestion to add a batch update :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a bunch. Had to modify it a bit, making some fields final. Now its just up to me to make it "mine" so to speak. Just wondering, with models (own extending Abstract, or Default) the view and all the levels of inherited methods for each involved class... thats like hundreds of possible things to try that seem they should work. For a noob like me its like trying to find a needle in a heystack. So, how on earth did you find this solution? Id love to pick your brain xD

Comment: @brat Years of banging my head against brick walls ;) - When I started, I never learnt the `DefaultTableModel`, I learnt from using the `AbstractTableModel`, I also didn't have the `RowSorter` API, had to roll my own, so I kinda of learnt a lot from doing those things by hand - and lots of blogs and forums ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to keep your sorting when set a new preferred index?
you only have three columnheaders(limited),why not set a priority about columnheaders?
when you click on one header,change its priority to first,reduce others by one.
and caculate the total sorting again to show them.

Answer (score 0):

> I chose to change the data with DefaultTableModel.setDataVector(), instead of row by row which seems bulky if lots of rows change.

Seems reasonable if all the data is changing since you will only generated a single event to repaint the whole table instead of one event for every row.

However, if you only change data on a few random rows then I would just update individual row, then you won't have the sorting issue.

For the first approach try the following:

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columNames); 
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);
```

this should prevent the `TableColumnModel` from being recreated when the `setDataVector(...)` is invoked, which results in the `TableStructureChanged` event being generated, which results in you losing the RowSorter. (or maybe you still lose the RowSorter, I've never tried it, but I do know you won't lose custom renderers/editors with this approach).

```
//model.fireTableRowsUpdated(0, model.getRowCount() -1 );
```

That is never needed. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke the proper event when the data is changed.

Comment: Have you tested it? I tried it and it doesn't seem to work, the `RowSorter` still seems to get reset

Comment: @MadProgrammer, no I haven't tried it as I noted in my response. I guess I won't make this suggestion again :)

Comment: Dam, I was hoping it would work and I was doing something wrong :(

Comment: I have trouble understanding why the RowSorter resets to begin with as default o_O. or why they call a method "setSortOnUpdates()" and then apparently doesnt do that unless you use a specific method to change the data :o.

Answer (score 0):

I came across that same problem and after looking into JDK source the simplest way to restore sorting seems to be sub-classing JTable with following code (this however does not fix another problem - selection is also being reset and needs to be restored).

```
RowSorter<? extends TableModel> lastRowSorter;
List<? extends RowSorter.SortKey> lastSortKeys;

@Override
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    lastRowSorter = getRowSorter();
    lastSortKeys = (lastRowSorter == null) ? null : lastRowSorter.getSortKeys();

    super.tableChanged(e);
}

@Override
public void createDefaultColumnsFromModel() {
    super.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();
    if( lastSortKeys != null ) {
        setRowSorter(lastRowSorter);
        lastRowSorter.setSortKeys(lastSortKeys);
    }
}
```